# CKEditor 4 - add div tags inside p tags

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I need to add div tags (as inline blocks) inside p tags in CKEditor 4. Simplified example of a source code I would like to add:

```
<p>This is a <div>DIV tag</div> inside a P tag.</p>
```

For some reason, CKE does not allow this. When adding the div, CKE automatically closes the surrounding p tag before adding the div. Result after adding the source code in CKE:

```
<p>This is a</p>

<div>DIV tag</div>
inside a P tag.

<p></p>
```

Is it possible to disable this automatic behavior so that div tags can be added inside p tags?